# Case Manager not updating correctly (CiviCRM 4.7.21)

Tags: civicase, roles

When I added some case roles and set the case manager to one of these roles it doesn't appear to update on the case summary screen.

1. Set up case
   http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/a/#/caseType
2. Add role
3. Set manager
4. View the case summary [image]

No matter which case role I set the case manager to, it still shows as Case Coordinator is (Case Manager) in the first column of the table shown.

I think this is a bug, but if it is, has anyone else come across this?

Comment: I came across a similar problem: If you have already added activity types to a case and change them afterwards (e.g. the label), those chanegs will not bereflected in the case type. I think that changes after defining the case type are not dealt with...

Comment: Can you also confirm that when trying to delete the case role, it still appears there? I tried editing the name of the user and nothing happens either.

Answer (score 4):

We have found that this is a bug.

If you're a developer the function which isn't working properly is in: -
CRM/Case/XMLProcessor/Process.php
Line 199 was checking whether $relationshipTypeXML->manager was set, as opposed to whether $relationshipTypeXML->manager == 1

Comment: Did this make it to JIRA? Was there a fix?

Comment: Sorry @petednz-fuzion we didn't submit a patch